# How can I prevent the Facebook like button from needing to be double tapped when I run it on an iPhone?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

It works but after 2 touches exactly. I'm using JavaScript and HTML. Any or all three would be great but I don't know. This is and example of type code I used to fix the zooming in too far problem. So a code in this way would be best.

```xml
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, 
  maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

Answer (score 0):

I found [a good resource](https://tomanistor.com/blog/fixing-the-ios-mobile-double-click-link-issue/) on this here. It has to do with changing styles on hover. Although there's no way to know for sure since you didn't share any related code.

That source also points to [this page](https://css-tricks.com/annoying-mobile-double-tap-link-issue/) which may help even more.